# ZMQ patterns; send then receive

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I have been reading up on zmq design patterns but I haven't seem to find that fits my need.

```
1. Box A sends info (json) to Box B and C; B and C gets different info from each other  
2. Boxes B and C do some work based on info received from Box A  
3. After finishing the work, Boxes B and C sends result back to Box A
```

Forwarder device (http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/devices/forwarder.html) can achieve step 1 and 2 but not 3, correct?

Are there any patterns I can use to achieve?
Is it simple request/reply pattern?
If so, is there a centralized request/reply pattern so that Box A doesnt pick Boxes B and C but rather Box A sends info to something central and it knows to send to Boxes B and C and send the result back to Box A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a pretty basic Load Balancing pattern which is in the guide. A is the controller and will be a ROUTER, while the workers, B and C, are DEALERS. The messaging is simple enough; the dealers send an initial message to the controller to say "I'm ready". The controller then hands out work to the ready workers.

This topology is the opposite of Jason's answer. Which you choose just depends on how you're wanting to extend your application. When the controller hands out work, it really ought to go to a worker that is ready to handle it. With the Load Balancing pattern that is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty basic DEALER/ROUTER pattern.

DEALER sockets are round-robin, which means it'll send one request to box B, then the next to box C, then the next to box B, etc. If you want to hold any work until the worker is completed, you just have to know the current count of available workers.

On box B and box C, use a ROUTER socket (or a REP socket if your use case is simple enough, but that'll limit your options).  Receive the work, work on it, send it back, wait for more work.

There are many examples like this in [the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all), which I recommend you read.

Comment: The main problem with this topology comes when the application gets extended. If there are more jobs than workers, the jobs ought to be handed out to a worker that's able to handle it. With this pattern, jobs get handed out to workers in round robin style, regardless of whether the assigned worker is busy and the relative size of the work packets. That can lead to bottlenecks. The Load Balancing pattern avoids those bottlenecks.

Comment: You're right, it's been almost a year since I first read through the guide, my memory of this particular pattern just got flipped, reversing the sockets is the more robust pattern (at least in the general case)... but the main advice from both our answers remains the same: read the guide, it addresses all of the basic use cases like this.